# Skewing main container skews image inside how to avoid content from skewing

Tags: html, css

I need to skew the main container which is `li` but not the content inside.

I am able to skew each `li`  but it also skew's contents inside

```
.cbp-rfgrid li {
  transform: skew(-25deg)
}
```

and when I add counter skew for image it add while triangle like shape on the corners

```
.cbp-rfgrid li a img {
 /* transform:skew(25deg)*/
}
```

I have set up CodePen [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNWPwr)

How can i skew `li` and not the content with our any white area around the image.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid">
  <!--item-->
  <li>
    <a href="albums/6/crisis-relief">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Footbal </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Cricket </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="albums/5/health">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Skiing</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Boxing </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div style="position: absolute; height: auto; display: block; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); "></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Baseball  </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); height: auto; display: block;">

        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); "></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Category Six  </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Category Seven</h3>
        <span class="cause-count">Albums (0)</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Category EIGHT </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <!--item-->
</ul>
```

Comment: are you just trying to make rhombus shaped list items, and that the background image and text you want to not be skewed?

Comment: No, I want it only skewwed at 25 deg but without skewing contents

Comment: so the background image AND the text must not be skewed? or only the text must not be skewed?

Comment: @haxxxton, Something like this https://www.mathsisfun.com/images/quadrilateral-rhombus.gif

Comment: Yes, as mentioned iin the question

Comment: nowhere in your question do you mention the background image.. also.. Me: "do you want a rhombus with not skewed background image and text".. You: "No, I want a rhombus with a not skewed background image and text".. *confused face*.. working on a solution for you now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you skew the `img` element back to displace the skew effect on the parent, you need to increase the size of the `img` element in order to compensate for the size adjustments otherwise there will be white space like you are seeing.

One option would be to scale the `a` element up so that the `img` element will increase in size and take up the extra white space.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyzaZj)

```
.cbp-rfgrid li {
  transform:skew(-25deg)
}
.cbp-rfgrid li a {
  transform: skew(25deg) scale(1.3);
}
```

Alternatively you could also apply the scaling to the `img` element depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Here is an updated snippet with your full code:

```css
.cbp-rfgrid {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.cbp-rfgrid li {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 4);
}
.cbp-rfgrid li a,
.cbp-rfgrid li a img {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.cbp-rfgrid li a img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.cbp-rfgrid li a div {
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(71, 163, 218, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
}
.cbp-rfgrid li a:hover div {
  background-color: rgba(204, 16, 64, 0.7);
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 #000000;
}
.cbp-rfgrid li a div h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}
.album-causes-list-h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.album-causes-albums-h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.album-causes-albums-h4 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.album-causes-albums-h4-cname {
  color: #cc1040;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}
.album-list-div {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.cbp-rfgrid-albums-list a:hover div {
  background-color: rgba(96, 80, 76, 0.8) !important;
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 #000000 !important;
}
.cause-count {
  bottom: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px #000000;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .cbp-rfgrid li {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1190px) {
  .cbp-rfgrid li {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 945px) {
  .cbp-rfgrid li {
    width: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .cbp-rfgrid li {
    width: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .cbp-rfgrid li {
    width: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .cbp-rfgrid li {
    width: calc(100% / 1);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .cbp-rfgrid li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/*SKEW CODE HERE*/

.cbp-rfgrid li {
  transform: skew(-25deg)
}
.cbp-rfgrid li a {
  transform: skew(25deg) scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid">
  <!--item-->
  <li>
    <a href="albums/6/crisis-relief">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Footbal </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Cricket </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="albums/5/health">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Skiing</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Boxing </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div style="position: absolute; height: auto; display: block; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); "></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Baseball  </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); height: auto; display: block;">

        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); "></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Category Six  </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Category Seven</h3>
        <span class="cause-count">Albums (0)</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/India_Gate_600x400.jpg">
      <div>
        <h3 class="album-causes-list-h3">Category EIGHT </h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <!--item-->
</ul>
```

Comment: SO that is the trick i dodnt new how to use scale with transform. I tried different way but ended with same problem

Comment: This looks like a solution but i am not sure if there is anyother way of doing it without scaling it or zooming it

Comment: @Learning - If you don't scale or stretch the image, I don't think there is any way for it to take up the remaining space and fill the whitespace (otherwise it would just be the same size as it initially was).